# I need to learn vuex in short time because and i cant figure out how to migrate my vue js to vuex?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuex

This is my github page and you can see what i have done in the help branch: https://github.com/maltin1234/blog

I need to change the code in the components but i dont know how.

### CreateComponent.vue

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <h1>Create A Post</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="addPost">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="post.title" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post Body:</label>
            <textarea
              class="form-control"
              v-model="post.body"
              rows="5"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
export default {

<script>
export default {
  name: "CreateComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addPost"]),
    onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.addPost(this.title);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

---

I have a node js backend and i want my vuex to fetch those endpoints. The node js backend consists of a mongodb connection and a model with articles. This is my try with vuex.

post.js (vue.js project)

```
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  posts: [],
};

const getters = {
  allPosts: (state) => state.Posts,
};

const actions = {
  //an action: makes a request, gets a response and calls a mutation
  async fetchPosts({ commit }) {
    // commit - to call the mutation
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/posts");
    commit("setPosts", response.data);
  },
  async addPosts({ commit }, title) {
    const response = await axios.post("", { title, completed: false });
    commit("newPost", response.data);
  },
  async deletePosts({ commit }, id) {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/delete/${id}`);
    commit("removePosts", id);
  },
  async filterPosts({ commit }, e) {
    //Get selected number
    // const limit = parseInt(e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].innerText);
    const limit = e.target.value;
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/posts`);
    commit("setPosts", response.data);
  },
  async updatePosts({ commit }, updatePosts) {
    const response = await axios.put(
      `http://localhost:4000/posts/update/${this.$route.params.id}`,
      updatePosts
    );
    console.log(response.data);
    commit("updatePosts", response.data);
  },
};

const mutations = {
  setPosts: (state, Posts) => (state.posts = posts),
  newPosts: (state, posts) => state.posts.unshift(posts),
  removePosts: (state, id) =>
    (state.posts = state.posts.filter((posts) => posts.id !== id)),
  updatePosts: (state, updTodo) => {
    const index = state.Posts.findIndex((posts) => posts.id === updPosts.id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      state.posts.splice(index, 1, updPosts);
    }
  },
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};
```

store.js

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";
import todos from "./modules/todos";

//load Vuex

Vue.use(Vuex)

//create store
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        posts
    }
})
```

Node project (https://github.com/maltin1234/blognode)

Comment: how are you calling `fetchPosts` `addPosts` `deletePosts` `filterPosts` and `updatePosts`? and where are you creating a Vuex store? There's absolutely no reference to `Vuex` in your code - besides `mapActions` which is never used

Comment: @JaromandaX I have a second branch in this repository. It is called help. Index.js would be the store. I was getting inspiration from this repo: https://github.com/bertamatu/vuex-todo-app. I am not sure how to do with the components.

Comment: You misunderstand ... I was referring to the code in the QUESTION ... not some github content that is irrelevant - or will be once you change it

Comment: @JaromandaX I updated the code here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly for using Vuex you have create your store and add it into your project, then for using any actions/state/getters/setters you have to import them into your component via vuex methods, for instance:

```
import { mapActions, mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState('yourModule', ['stateValueOne', 'stateValueTwo'])
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapAction('yourModule', ['actionOne', 'actionTwo'])
    }
}
```

Then you can get them by `this` identifier
Simply check Vuex API Reference, It's pretty simple

Comment: Can you take a look at my answer and tell me if that is correct that you meant?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the name from index.js to store.js

```
store.js
import Vuex from "vuex";
import Vue from "vue";
import store from "./post";

//load Vuex
Vue.use(Vuex);

//create store
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    posts,
  },
});
```

Then i wasnt sure exactly how you meant dima but I changed my CreateComponent to this code.

CreateComponent.js

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Create A Post</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="addPost">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="post.title" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Post Body:</label>
            <textarea
              class="form-control"
              v-model="post.body"
              rows="5"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br />
      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
export default {

<script>
export default {
  name: "AddPost",
  data() {
    return {
      title: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["addPost"]),
    onSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.addPosts(this.title);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

And this is my post.js that does the requests to my backend
// here should be added: state, getters, actions, mutations

```
import axios from "axios";

const state = {
  posts: [],
};

const getters = {
  allPosts: (state) => state.Posts,
};

const actions = {
  //an action: makes a request, gets a response and calls a mutation
  async fetchPosts({ commit }) {
    // commit - to call the mutation
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/posts");
    commit("setPosts", response.data);
  },
  async addPosts({ commit }, title) {
    const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/posts/add", {
      title,
      completed: false,
    });
    commit("newPost", response.data);
  },
  async deletePosts({ commit }, id) {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/posts/delete/${id}`);
    commit("removePosts", id);
  },
  async filterPosts({ commit }, e) {
    //Get selected number
    // const limit = parseInt(e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].innerText);
    const limit = e.target.value;
    const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/posts`);
    commit("setPosts", response.data);
  },
  async updatePosts({ commit }, updatePosts) {
    const response = await axios.put(
      `http://localhost:4000/posts/update/${this.$route.params.id}`,
      updatePosts
    );
    console.log(response.data);
    commit("updatePosts", response.data);
  },
};

const mutations = {
  setPosts: (state, posts) => (state.posts = posts),
  newPosts: (state, posts) => state.posts.unshift(posts),
  removePosts: (state, id) =>
    (state.posts = state.posts.filter((posts) => posts.id !== id)),
  updatePosts: (state, updPosts) => {
    const index = state.Posts.findIndex((posts) => posts.id === updPosts.id);
    if (index !== -1) {
      state.posts.splice(index, 1, updPosts);
    }
  },
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations,
};

//this is a boilerplate for vuex module
```